# How do I make my Htaccess remove Extension, while not having a filename after directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm coding in PHP, and have implemented a htaccess code which removes the file extension (in this case '.php').

The problem is, this doesn't allow directories to remove the index.php on the end.

I.E. http://www.domain.com/about/ - The requested URL /about/.php was not found on this server.

Here is my current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

I want to have /about/ redirect to /about/index.php, while just showing /about/

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use DirectorySlash in htaccess file
 apatche automatically appends trailing slash after directory names

```
DirectorySlash On
```

if you want  call the directory without the trailing slash try:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't fixed it. It's throwing the same error.